# Asp.net Redirect after a Javascript alert breaks it

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net, redirect

In code behind I'm currently using an alert after submitting a form.

It alerts the user with success message then redirects him to "OtherPage.aspx" using Javascript

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "Success", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The windows has been successfully updated ');window.location='OtherPage.aspx';</script>'")
```

I would like to add a code under It to redirect the user in case javascript is off

But the problem is if I write Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect the alert will no longer show up

Comment: If JavaScript is off the alert will not show up in any case

Comment: If you want to account for the case where user has JS turned off you will need to pop server side modal window with the "OK" button. Once user clicks that button you will do Response.Redirect to the new page.

Comment: @AlexanderM "server side modal window" ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I meant show modal window from server side (basically if you you declare such modal window as asp:Panel with Visible=False swap it on the server to True). He should use that modal window instead of alert.

Comment: Ah, yes. display message via ASPX/HTML markup. Makes sense. For a second there I thought you meant displaying actual window on the server.